# ADF Filter Activity throwing error - Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'

Tags: filter, android-activity, oracle-adf

I have an ADF pipeline in which there is a Web Activity called Web1 that pulls JSON data from a REST API. Below is the sample data:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjWIi.png)

I am passing this data to a filter activity where I am trying to filter the record where Name is equal to 'John'.
The Filter activity options I selected are as below:

Item is @activity('Web').output.response.Name
Condition is @equals(item(),'John')

However, I am getting the below error.

The expression `'activity('Web1').output.response.Name'` cannot be evaluated because property 'Name' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'.

I expect the Filter activity to not error out.